# Images Appearing in Different Widths in Cell of Programatic UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have created a UITableView programmatically. I set the size for an image using the following code and then place various images in it. Most images display fine but occasionally one will display too narrow or way too wide.

Similar code works fine for UITableViews I have created in storyboard except that in that case I set the image size in storyboard, whereas here, I am setting it as shown below.  Here is my code:

```
//make tableview

self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(160, 114, 140, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
       _myTableView.rowHeight=24;

//In cellforrowatindexpath
  cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,24,24);
  float imageWidth =cell.imageView.frame.size.width;
//THis is always 24 due to framesize set above but I have it here to check
 cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
 cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [cell.imageView layoutIfNeeded];//THIS HAS NO EFFECT
```

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Looks like autolayout changes the size of UIImageView to have intrinsic size of correspond image right after layoutIfNeeded call.

Comment: It does the same thing without layoutIfNeeded.  However, the intrinsic size might have something to do with it.  I have not put constraints in the code as they are such a hassle to do.

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill change this to AspectFit

Comment: AspectFit looks the same as Fill

Answer (score 0):

add at your tableview a custom cell with a UIImageView, I not sure the reason, but you can't resize the default uiimage of the tableview.
like this:

```
//  ViewController.m
//  StackOverflowOBJC
//
//  Created by Ramires Moreira on 5/15/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ramires Moreira. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController  ()

@end

@implementation ViewController  

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [table setDelegate:self];
    [table setDataSource:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:table];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // create a cell
    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[tableView layer] bounds].size.width, 300);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame];

    //create a image view with a image
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(33, 10, 90, 90);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];

    // get a image from the Assests
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jobs"];
    [imageView setImage:image];

    //configure the imageView
    [ imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;


    // create a label
    CGFloat height = cell.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = [[cell layer] bounds].size.width;
    CGRect frameLabel = CGRectMake(300, height/2, width, height);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameLabel];
    label.text = @"teste";

    //add all subviews
    [cell addSubview:label];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
// resize your cell
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return  110.0;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you mean subclass uitableviewcell?

Comment: The tableview is created in code.  No storyboard, so you can't drag and drop.

Comment: and now? it help you?